# Can't make a git commit with more than one word in vscode

Tags: git

Hello guys I am new to vscode I try to make a commit on vscode with more than one word as in "I edited  forms.py"  I get these errors

```
(django1901) D:\django-practice\model_form\modelapp>git commit -m 'I edited  forms.py'
error: pathspec 'edited' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'file'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

please I need help in figuring this out

Comment: Try double quotes

Comment: Please this should be formatted as code error  "error: pathspec 'edited' did not match any file(s) known to git. error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git. error: pathspec 'file'' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: Are you entering that in a terminal window (i.e. not a VS Code problem) or is this output from the Source Control support in VS Code?

Comment: @crashmstr thanks for your response yes I am entering it on vscode terminal I changed the terminal from Power Shell to cmd.

Comment: @Benedict In that case, this has nothing to do with VS Code. It would be the same if you opened up a cmd.exe window by itself.

Comment: @crashmstr thanks for the reply, you are very right. How do I solve it?

Comment: Try using `"` do delineate strings instead of `'`.

Comment: @crashmstr thank you very much it worked using "I added a file" worked instead of 'I added a file'

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes instead of single quotes should do the trick:

Example:

```
git commit -m "I edited  forms.py"
```